# Read/write data from COM port in Android

Tags: android, serial-port, usbserial

I need connecting Android tablet with some COM port device and send commands to them.

How I understend, I need USB-COM port adapter. What type of adapter I need? Some requirements?
When I connect device via USB-COM port adapter, how I must to work with him? Maybe some examples?